# combining CSV files from Covid-data

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to combine the CSV files from the Johns Hopkins Covid Data (e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/05-10-2020.csv & https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-23-2020.csv).

I already managed to load the files into a DataFrame as well as sanitizing the header (_ vs. / in some names). Now I want to pick one column (e.g. Confirmed), rename it to the day of the file and then combine those CSV files to get a progress over time.

This merge needs to be done by state_province. In both frames, the key may not be present. How can I do this? I experimented with rightjoin and outerjoin, but didn't have any success. Can someone point me the right way please?

I initially didn't want to share the code that I have so far because I didn't want to guide to a specific solution - but here it is. It is copied together from several Jupyter cells.

```
using Dates

start = Dates.Date(2020,1,22) #begin of recording
now = Dates.Date(Dates.now())- Dates.Day(1) #today
date_range = collect(start:Dates.Day(1):now) #create a date range with 1 element per day
prefix = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/"
suffix = ".csv"

function create_url(date)
    return prefix * Dates.format(date, "mm-dd-YYYY") * suffix
end

function cleanup_column_names(name)
   if name == "Country/Region" || name == "Country_Region" 
        return "country"
    elseif name == "Province/State" || name == "Province_State"
        return "state"
    else
        return name
    end
end

using CSV
using HTTP
using DataFrames

selected_data = "Confirmed"
date = date_range[1]

data = DataFrame(CSV.File(HTTP.get(create_url(date)).body))
DataFrames.rename!(cleanup_column_names, data)
DataFrames.select!(data,["state", "country", selected_data])
DataFrames.rename!(data, 3 => Dates.format(date, "YYYY-mm-dd"))
```

Regards
Tobias

Comment: can you pass the code you have up till this point? Then I can help you with what you should do.

Comment: Can you specify what your output should look like? One DataFrame with date and cases per row?

Comment: @chefhose each row a state/province and each column the confirmed cases on a single day for example.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Did you solve your problem? I believe that I can help you with another tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to Julia, so take my answer with a bit of scepticism:

First, we wrap the DataFrame creation into a function:

```
function prepare_date_df(date)
    data = DataFrame(CSV.File(HTTP.get(create_url(date)).body))
    DataFrames.rename!(cleanup_column_names, data)
    DataFrames.select!(data,["state", "country", selected_data])
    DataFrames.rename!(data, 3 => Dates.format(date, "YYYY-mm-dd"))
    return data
end
```

Let's create our first Dataframe:

```
df = prepare_date_df(date_range[1])
```

Now, let's iterate over all the other dates, create a dataframe for each date and merge this with our first dataframe:

```
for date in date_range[2:end]
    df_new = prepare_date_df(date)
    df = outerjoin(df, df_new, on = [:state, :country])
end
```

This works fine for the first two months, but with the growing Dataframes, it suddenly gets very slow (and even hangs?). So I would be very interested in a more performative answer!